# Calling environment variables inside class not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure why this isn't working?  I want to be able to access the constants set in my `.env.php` file but NetBeans is showing an error stating that the `getenv` function isn't recognized.

Here is my code

```
<?php 

class Blah extends Eloquent {
...
protected $connection = getenv('DB_NAME');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? What version of PHP are you running? You can't set property definitions to general expressions until PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the class values from the constructor.

```
class Blah extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = null;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = getenv('DB_NAME');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question.  Does the __construct() affect the parent class in any way?

Comment: It depends. The parent class constructor is not called automatically, you would need do a parent::__construct(); to call it. Take an eye on the variable names and their scopes. It's possible to overwrite variables declared in the parent, from the child. If $connection should exist in Eloquent, you are re-declaring it in Blah.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $connection = getenv('DB_NAME');
```

That code is invalid. You can't declare class properties like that.

> ...but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must
>   be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on
>   run-time information in order to be evaluated [0]

[0] http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: This is true up to version 5.5. From PHP 5.7 it will work - with constants and functions.